# CakePHP Migration CreateTable Fail

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I am going to learn bake migration command in cake php,
so I created a table named `product` by 
`bin/cake bake migration CreateProduct`
and `bin/cake migration migrate`

To make this again as training, I dropped this table by `drop table product` and deleted the Migration php file, and

`bin/cake bake migration CreateTableName 
name:string description:text created modified`

worked and migration file was made successfully

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateProducts extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('products');
        $table->addColumn('name', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 255,
                'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('des', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 255,
                'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('text', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 255,
                'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('created', 'datetime', [
                'default' => null,
                'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('modified', 'datetime', [
                'default' => null,
                'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
}
```

and also migrated file was made

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class Migrate extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
    }
}
```

but the table cannot found!

How I can make a table which name is same as dropped table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the table by bake command, and deleted by drop, sql command, that was mistake. So I made drop migration file by `bin/cake bake migration DropTableName` Then Migrated, and new `product` table was made.

Comment: If your initial migration was just a test that you needed to undo, you might look into the "rollback" option of migrations as a cleaner way.